# Date time format is not working

Tags: asp.net, datetime

I am trying to get today's Date and time , in this kind of format,

```
2016-12-28 09:50:12.960
```

I used this to convert it to that ("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") but its not working , I want it to save it here in this line of code,

```
 DetailsViewDS.InsertParameters["CreatedDate"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

Any tips guys?

Comment: Is `CreatedDate` a `DateTime` in the database? If so, you should just assign the `DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()` directly. If you need the string representation, the answer by @IzzetYildirim looks ok, except that you probably want `HH`, not `hh`. Lower case version uses a 12 hour clock...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format lacks milliseconds. Try following.

```
string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: Thanks mate, will try this one.